# What does VC9 stand for in PHP version?

Tags: php

I need to know what does VC stand for in the PHP version:

> VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe (2011-Nov-10 19:52:12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on the other (also correct) answers a little further, from [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/):

> **Which version (of PHP for Windows) do I choose?**
>
> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need
>   to use the VC6 versions of PHP.
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you should use the VC9 versions of PHP.
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler.
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the Visual Studio 2008 compiler and
>   have improvements in performance and stability. The VC9 versions
>   require you to have the [Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF) or the
>   [Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bd2a6171-e2d6-4230-b809-9a8d7548c1b6&displaylang=en) installed.
>
> Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org binaries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

that's Visual Studio.  VC9 is Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 3):

I believe this refers to the compiler version.  In this case, MS Visual Studio C/C++ version 9.

[Visuall C++ wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++)